# PidTagInternetCodePage not present in msg file

Tags: email, outlook, stream, ole, msg

Looking at the [MS-OXPROPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148), [MS-OXCMSG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7fd7ec40-deec-4c06-9493-1bc06b349682%28Office.15%29.aspx) and [MS-OXCMAIL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcmail/b60d48db-183f-4bf5-a908-f584e62cb2d4) documentation, it is said that the user should include PidTagInternetCodePage to indicate the appropriate code page for the HTML content in order to parse it properly.

However, opening up the ole streams of the msg files, I could not find the `0x3FDE` stream that indicates the code page id, but only found some semblance of a code page id in the compressed RTF stream (first line).

Am I looking at the streams wrongly or are the other properties hidden in other streams? If so, how do I look for them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `PidTagInternetCodePage` property is not guaranteed to be present and is in no way required, especially if it is a Unicode MSG file. The HTML body can include the meta tag with encoding in the header, and even then, it won't be necessary if all Unicode characters in the HTML body are properly HTML-encoded (which is always a good idea).